# An Inequality of Expected Value of Random Variables

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I encountered the following problem in my research:

Suppose there are $N$ random variables that are independent and identically distributed (IID). The probability density function (PDF) of these random variables $f(x)$ is a unimodal function symmetrical about $0$ (i.e., $f(x)$ is non-decreasing within $(-∞,0)$, and for any $x$, $f(x) = f(-x)$ holds. for example, the distribution can be uniform distribution, normal distribution, Cauchy distribution with mean $0$, etc.).
For a given real number $x_0$, Sort these random variables as $X_1, X_2, …, X_N$ such that $$|X_1-x_0|\leq |X_2-x_0| \leq … \leq |X_N-x_0|$$
For example, if $N = 3$, the $N$ random variables are randomly chosen as $-0.5, 1.5, 5$, and $x_0 = 1$, then $X_1 = 1.5, X_2 = -0.5, X_3 = 5$.
Let $Y_i = |\frac{X_1+X_2+…+X_i}{i}-x_0|^r (i=1,…,N, r = 1\ or\ 2)$,  then for any $x_0$ and $f(x)$, does the inequality
$$EY_1 \leq EY_2 \leq… \leq EY_N$$
always hold? Where $E$ denotes the expected value.

I tested the inequality above via the Monte Carlo method for cases where the distributions are uniform distribution, normal distribution, and Cauchy distribution, and the results are shown in the following figure respectively, where the x-axis stands for $x_0$, the y-axis stands for the expected value, and the legend '$i$' stands for the expected value of $Y_i$. It can be seen that, for any $x_0$, $EY_1 \leq EY_2 \leq… \leq EY_N$ holds.
[image: Fig. 1 Normal Distribution]
[image: Fig. 2 Uniform Distribution]
[image: Fig. 3 Cauchy Distribution]

Moreover, is it possible to derive the PDF of $Y_i$?

Answers or ideas for either $r=1$ or $r=2$ would be so grateful!

Comment: Can you give an example (take it from your textbook if you like) of what you call a PDF   $f(x)$ which is nondecreasing on $(-\infty, 0)$ and satisfies $f(x) = f(-x)$ as you say it does? It appears to me that since $f(x)$ is nondecreasing on $(-\infty, 0)$, it should be non-increasing on $(0,\infty)$.  Lots of people use CDF and $F(x)$ for what you call a PDF $f(x)$ and use pdf as an abbreviation for probability _density_ function.  pdfs can be symmetric (or _even_) functions whereas PDFs cannot be symmetric as you think they are. They increase from value $0$ to value $1$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate It seems fairly likely from context that the OP meant probability density function.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yes, it is a probability density function. A typo... sorry

Comment: you can try post it (also) on math overflow to maximize your chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384974/an-inequality-of-expected-value-of-random-variables @MikeG please don't recommend posting to MO without also suggesting the OP wait a decent interval, at least a few days.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: Oh, sorry about that...

Comment: @MikeG that's ok, it's just nice to let the Math.SE community a proper go at the question first.